# Excel Formula: SUMIFS, SUMPRODUCT?? Not sure

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

So I'm in a pickle where I can't figure out what formula to use in this situation. Long story short this is a forecasting tool for construction and this sample is very basic. Yes, I know this could be done simply with 3 different `IF` formulas but this is for large 3+ year construction projects which are sometimes forecasted weekly so I'd prefer to be able to grab the whole section and simply make that work. I've tried using various of `SUMIFS` or `SUMPRODUCT` with no luck, anyone have any ideas?

My goal would be in this example to have `L11` in the attached image equal the sum of all the highlighted yellow cells IF and only IF, the adjacent blue cell to the right of that yellow cell is blank. So once you enter actual costs, it only totals projected costs for which actuals haven't been plugged in yet. Is there some type of way to say take this whole row of items (`N11:Y11`) and total all cells that have "Proj ($)" in row 4 IF row 4 "Act ($)" does not equal blank?

[image: Attached image]

Comment: Are you trying Cell Colors to get SUM in L11 ??

Answer (score 1):

A `SUMIFS` can do it for you with a judicious choice of ranges:

```
=SUMIFS($O11:$W11,O$4:W$4,"Proj ($)",$P11:$X11,"<>",$P$4:$X$4,"Act ($)")
```

Note that it's important that all ranges are the same size for the `SUMIFS` to work

Answer (score 0):

**Your problem can be solved by using `IF` & `SUMIF` combination:**

[image]

- Enter this Formula in Cell `C205`.

  `=IF(AND($A$202:$K$202<>"",$A$201:$J$201="Act($)"),SUMIF($A201:$J201,"=Proj($)",$A$202:$K$202),0)`

**How it works:**

**Situation 1:**

- Column heading are `Act($)` and in `Row 202`,
  out of `3` Cells, `2` cells are blank,
  therefore the Formula `SUMs` those Cells has
  Column Heading `Proj($)` and returns `19485` is
  equals to `(6495+6495+6495)`.

**Situation 2:**

- Column heading are `Act($)` and in `Row 202`,
  out of `3` cells, all `3` cells are blank,
  therefore the Formula doesn't `SUMs`
  those Cells has Column Heading `Proj($)` and
  returns `0`.

*Adjust cell reference in the Formula as needed.*